# Jasper reports: the first element of the collection bean is skipped

Tags: jasper-reports, javabeans, tableofcontents

When using an abstract report and content pages plus a bean collection as a data source the first element of the collection is skipped

Has someone stumbled upon the same problem? I've tried multiple things and read quite a few posts here and in the Jasper Reports community without success

Code of the abstract book (main):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Abstract_refactored" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" sectionType="Part" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="d2716064-8ae4-40cf-a575-33afba400e3a">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.header" value="Cover and Table of Contents"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.footer" value="Backcover"/>
        <parameter name="ubersichtCollectionRefactored" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
        <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/Users/Beer/JaspersoftWorkspace/MyReports/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="CollectionBeanParam" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
        <group name="cover"/>
        <detail>
            <part evaluationTime="Now" uuid="6b9e8284-92b6-4004-a896-77e6650f3afa">
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd" usingCache="false">
                    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ubersichtCollectionRefactored}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="ubersichtCollectionRefactored">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ubersichtCollectionRefactored}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "ubersicht_refactored.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
            <part uuid="3bbe9fbc-42db-4b15-8120-416514e99d4c">
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportParameter name="CollectionBeanParam">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CollectionBeanParam}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CollectionBeanParam}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "investmentcosts.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

Content page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="investmentcosts" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="febeabfd-a22b-490f-8e0b-ff52efdc9ffa">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="investmentCostDataset" uuid="1fe5fdcb-a4b2-4546-bd90-2f5578170233">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <field name="product" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="cost" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="CollectionBeanParam" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="257" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="524" height="150" uuid="5922b981-1b64-4daa-b492-c1b03192d003">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="investmentCostDataset" uuid="9d4a3bba-0367-4a02-9a12-5d69ea0f77c8">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CollectionBeanParam}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{CollectionBeanParam}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="260" uuid="7e3b0b3c-03c7-438d-8d74-c70c439d2ac6">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="260" height="30" uuid="88e907e3-8090-4c62-8b42-692390955241"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" rotation="None"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Produkt]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="260" height="30" uuid="66da7f58-d69f-4a13-b6d5-a8e37d7707b8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="2"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{product}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="130" uuid="c098c3a0-7e77-4a47-9b72-530d5a4b10ff">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="f64de092-ac20-4984-9b55-569910a31b6c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" rotation="None"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Menge]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="a62bdcb7-9257-4b0e-a0e9-10a94efc65f1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="130" uuid="2fe1cd34-cfc4-426b-b37a-9c1393bffe5b">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="67b1e188-c745-4651-a9a9-892d71c31255"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" rotation="None"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Preis]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="2888a61e-7a85-4117-91fc-cab41dc5e00a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cost}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Adding the java code:

```
    File fileAbstractBook = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:report/Abstract_refactored.jrxml");
    InputStream inputAbstractBook = new FileInputStream(fileAbstractBook.getAbsolutePath());
    JasperDesign  jasperAbstractBook = JRXmlLoader.load(inputAbstractBook);
    JasperReport abstractBook = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperAbstractBook);
    
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(investmentCostsList);
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource2 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(ubersichtList);
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    

    //Path path = Paths.get(fileInvestmentCosts.getAbsolutePath());
    Path path = Paths.get(fileSub.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Path of the report resources"+ path.getParent());

    params.put("CollectionBeanParam", dataSource1);//ubersichtCollectionBeanParam
    params.put("ubersichtCollectionRefactored", dataSource2);//ubersichtCollectionBeanParam
    params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", path.getParent() + "/");
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(abstractBook, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

Comment: Are you reusing the same data source instance for two reports/subreports (for instance as REPORT_DATA_SOURCE for the book report)?  You need a fresh data source object for each report since the report consumes/iterates on the data source.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I use the REPORT_DATA_SOURCE for the 2 content reports but the issue happens in both. I had tried not to use the REPORT_DATA_SOURCE before but then the data was not passed to the content reports.

Comment: Can you post the Java code where you pass parameters to the book report?

Comment: Just edited my initial question with the java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `$P{CollectionBeanParam}` both as `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE`, which is used for the main report dataset, and as `CollectionBeanParam`, which gets passed as data source to the table subdataset.  The main dataset consumes the first record from the data source instance and then passes it to the table subdataset which iterates on the remaining records.

From the looks of it, the main dataset of the `investmentcosts` part doesn't read anything from the data source, therefore what you should do is to pass an empty data source as `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE` for the part.  As in

```
        <part uuid="3bbe9fbc-42db-4b15-8120-416514e99d4c">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="CollectionBeanParam">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CollectionBeanParam}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource()]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "investmentcosts.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
```

As a note, in the table `datasetRun` you have both `REPORT_DATA_SOURCE` as parameter and `dataSourceExpression`.  You only need one, although having both shouldn't break anything.